# Why does AT&T claim I used more data than my iPhone does?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers, data

I reset my data usage in Settings (iPhone 4s) at the start of every billing cycle. Every month I near my data limit of 2GB so it's important to me to be careful of this number. However it seems like every day myAT&T claims my data usage went up by something in the neighborhood of 10 to 30 MB more than the usage statistics in Settings say. Now I'm pretty sure Settings knows how much data is transferred. Why does AT&T inflate this, is there any way to get them to stop, and does any other provider not do this?

Comment: Did you tether at all?

Comment: No, AT&T doesn't let people in regular data plans to tether.

Comment: This is a great question that I would like an answer to.  AT&T claims I've used 6 times more data than my phone does.

Comment: @kal-al Do you have other devices that are linked to your same cellular plan, for example, an iPad?

Comment: @Angelplayer No I do not. Either I was somehow mistaken or AT&T gives faulty readings. It doesn't say I used 6 times more than the phone,though.

Answer (score 1):

The data counters on all phones are approximate, and they're most likely not artificially inflating your data usage. In the future, you can check AT&T's website to track the exact amount of data you'll be billed for.

Comment: I doubt AT&T's data estimates are more accurate than the device itself which knows what goes in and out.

Comment: AT&T did this to me several months in a row--including data charges on days I never went online, for anything--and of course, with Data turned off. I spent some time and energy arguing with the gorilla, and then I let it have it's way. For now.